# How to duplicate a block of polygons in svg at a different coordinate set?

Tags: html, svg

I'm a beginner in html/css/svg and I can't seem to figure out a way to duplicate this block of polygons to another point in the screen:

```html
<g id="hour10" style="fill-rule:evenodd; stroke:#FFFFFF; stroke-width:0.25; stroke-opacity:1; stroke-linecap:butt; stroke-linejoin:miter;">
            <polygon id="a" points=" 10, 10  20, 0  80, 0  90, 10  80, 20  20, 20" fill="#FF0000"/>
            <polygon id="b" points=" 90, 10 100, 20 100, 80  90, 90  80, 80  80, 20" fill="#FF0000"/>
            <polygon id="c" points=" 90, 90 100,100 100,160  90,170  80,160  80,100" fill="#FF0000"/>
            <polygon id="d" points=" 90,170  80,180  20,180  10,170  20,160  80,160" fill="#FF0000"/>
            <polygon id="e" points=" 10,170  0,160  0,100  10, 90  20,100  20,160" fill="#FF0000"/>
            <polygon id="f" points=" 10, 90  0, 80  0, 20  10, 10  20, 20  20, 80" fill="#FF0000"/>
            <polygon id="g" points=" 10, 90  20, 80  80, 80  90, 90  80,100  20,100" fill="#FF0000"/>
        </g>
```

I haven't been able to find anything that does this easily. Any help?

Comment: Try something like `<use href="#hour10" x="120" y="40" />` Use x and y attributes to set the new position

Comment: @enxanetaThank you so much! Is there any way to individually override certain elements of each use? For example, could I change the fill color of a polygon on one instance but not the others?

Comment: If the polygons have no fill you can use a fill attribute for the use element.

Comment: @enxaneta what would something like that look like if I wanted to be able to control the fill of each polygon within an instance?